# Парсинг JSON в Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

Помогите получить значение ключа "description", не могу понять как быть со значением ключа, который является массивом ключей

И где в этом случае писать as?, as! или as, в самом конце пример моего кода для блока "description", выдает ошибку в первой строке тип эниобджект не соотв. протоколу хэшбл

```
    {
"coord": {
"lon": 36.25,
"lat": 50
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 800,
"main": "Clear",
"description": "clear sky",
"icon": "01d"
}
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
"temp": 304.15,
"pressure": 1013,
"humidity": 38,
"temp_min": 304.15,
"temp_max": 304.15
},
"visibility": 10000,
"wind": {
"speed": 2,
"deg": 80
},
"clouds": {
"all": 0
},
"dt": 1502123400,
"sys": {
"type": 1,
"id": 7355,
"message": 0.0034,
"country": "UA",
"sunrise": 1502072034,
"sunset": 1502125587
},
"id": 706483,
"name": "Kharkiv",
"cod": 200
}

 if let weather = json["weather"] as? [AnyObject: [String]] {
     if let weatherDescription = weather["description"] as? String {
                        self.condition = weatherDescription
                        print(weatherDescription)
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, это ответ сервера в типа Data? Для начала нужно провести десериализацию:

```
// обработка исключения, data - ответ вашего сервера. as! пишется когда 100% уверен, что ответ 100% преобразуется в тип, к которому приводишь. не уверен - as? и json будет иметь опциональное значение
do {
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String, Any>

// получаем "description" и преобразуем его в массив словарей типа     <String, Array>
let weather = json["weather"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>

let description = weather[0]["description"] as! String
} catch {
print("Can't parse responce.")
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ, все работает на ура!

Answer (score 0):

Для получения значения description попробуйте следующее

```
//получаем погоду
if let weather = json["weather"] as? [String: AnyObject] {

    if let weatherDescription = weather["description"] as? String {

        // обрабатываете полученое описание погоды
        self.condition = weatherDescription
        print(weatherDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как я написал выше значение "value" ключа "weather" является массивом других словарей.

Comment: Если Вам интересен вопрос, то ответ ниже правильно раскрывает правильно

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите, можете воспользоваться новым API декодера в Swift 4. Тогда ключ description можно получить так:

```
weatherData.weather[0].description
```

Для этого вы описываете JSON данные обычной структурой (**struct**), которая соответствует протоколу **Decodable**.

```
import Foundation

struct WeatherData : Decodable {
    let coord: Coord
    let weather: [Weather]
    let base: String
    let main : Main
    let visibility : Int
    let wind : Wind
    let clouds : Clouds
    let dt : Int
    let sys : Sys
    let id : Int
    let name : String
    let cod : Int
    struct Coord : Decodable {
        let lon: Double
        let lat: Double
    }
    struct Weather : Decodable {
        let id: Int
        let main: String
        let description: String
        let icon: String
    }
    struct Main : Decodable {
        let temp : Double
        let pressure : Double
        let humidity : Double
        let temp_min : Double
        let temp_max : Double
    }
    struct Wind : Decodable {
        let speed: Int
        let deg : Int
    }
    struct Clouds : Decodable {
        let all : Int
    }
    struct Sys : Decodable {
        let type : Int
        let id : Int
        let message : Double
        let country : String
        let sunrise : Int
        let sunset  : Int
    }
}
```

Так будет выглядеть ваши исходные данные JSON.

```
let json = """
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 36.25,
        "lat": 50
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 800,
            "main": "Clear",
            "description": "clear sky",
            "icon": "01d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 304.15,
        "pressure": 1013,
        "humidity": 38,
        "temp_min": 304.15,
        "temp_max": 304.15
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 2,
        "deg": 80
        },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "dt": 1502123400,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 7355,
        "message": 0.0034,
        "country": "UA",
        "sunrise": 1502072034,
        "sunset": 1502125587
    },
    "id": 706483,
    "name": "Kharkiv",
    "cod": 200
}
"""
```

Декодер используется следующим образом.

```
func __test_so_703115() {
    print("[TEST]: \(#function)")
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
    let weatherData = try! decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from:data)
    print("Description: \(weatherData.weather[0].description)")
//    print(weatherData)
    print("[/TEST]")
}
```

На выходе будет то, что вам требуется — поле description.

```
[TEST]: __test_so_703115()
Description: clear sky
[/TEST]
```